# How to copy files with one extension to another extension

Tags: linux, unix

I have a.s b.s c.s d.s files in my current directory on my linux machine, I want to copy them to new extension .S like a.S b.S c.S d.S

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in `ls *.s`; do filename="${each%.*}"; extension="${each##*.}" ; do mv ${each} ${filename}".S" ; done;
```

Comment: The example could be shortened: the `extension` variable is set but not used, and the `filename` variable is set only once.

Comment: I left extension var there just for extra information. =]

Comment: A shorter example is (usually) easier to explain (unless it is in Perl).

Answer (score 0):

This script also would do it.

for file in *.s
do
    cp -i "${file}" "${file/.s/.S}"
done

Comment: That appears to be bash-specific (question is tagged with `unix`, and the syntax is not apparent in the POSIX [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18)).